# How to show the same element more than once in ng-show?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am playing around with a card game app, and I want a card image to show for each instance that is in the hand array. To keep it simple, I am looking to show card1.png if the array looks like [1,2,3,4,5]. However, I want the image to show twice if the array looks like [1,1,3,4,5]. So far, I can just get it to show once.

**Index.html**

```
<div ng-repeat="hand in hands track by $index">
    Player {{$index}} hand: {{ hand }}
    <img src="/images/faces-one.png" ng-show="numberInArray(hand, 1)">
    <img src="/images/two.png" ng-show="numberInArray(hand, 2)">
    <img src="/images/three.png" ng-show="numberInArray(hand, 3)">
    <img src="/images/four.png" ng-show="numberInArray(hand, 4)">
    <img src="/images/five.png" ng-show="numberInArray(hand, 5)">
    <img src="/images/six.png" ng-show="numberInArray(hand, 6)">  
</div>
```

**App.js**

```
$scope.numberInArray = function(hand, num) {
  var found;
  found = hand.includes(num) ? true : false;
  return found;
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't do this kind of calculation in the view file at all.  Even if you could fix the logic, this is very inefficient, because that function will be called ***six times!*** **every time a change is detected**.  Instead, you should build the array of images you want to use in your controller, and use `ng-src` or something similar.

Comment: in other words, there *should* be two loops here, one for the `hand in hands`, and one for the `card in hand`.

Comment: Despite my answer below, I do agree with @Claies. We should always do as much as possible in the controller.

Comment: @Claies Thanks for the response. Can you please post this in an answer so that I can accept. I will then post the code I have that fixed the problem.

Comment: @Matthew Cawley, many thanks for your suggested answer but I managed to go with a controller solution.

Comment: if you solved the problem, and have code for it, it would be much better for you to post your own answer demonstrating the solution.  A self answer is an accepted (and encouraged) practice, and your answer with a solution would be much better than my bit of info pointing you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the comments I received, this is the solution I implemented:

**Index.html**

```
<div ng-repeat="hand in hands track by $index">
     Player {{$index}} hand:
     <div ng-repeat="card in hand track by $index">
         <img ng-src="/images/{{card}}.png">
     </div>
</div>
```

The numberInArray function was removed as it was not required. Basically, This now iterates over the array of arrays, and displays the image found at the ng-src, which in this case would be 1.png, 2.png etc. This achieves my goal of showing the card image for each number in the array, regardless of its count.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not suggesting that this is the best solution, but to fix what you've currently got (or at least appear to have)...

Use another (nested)  `ng-repeat` on each image instead of `ng-show`. You should be able to attach it to a `getNunbersInArray(n)` function that returns a subset of the main array that can then be looped through the desired number of times.

For example, if you have `[1,1,3,4,5]` in your main array, the function connected to the new `ng-repeat`s would return `[1,1]` (when passed 1) and `[2]` (when passed 2), etc.

You don't need to do anything with the values returned in these new arrays, the only thing that matters is that they contain the correct number of elements to ensure that the image is repeated the correct number of times.